# Regex match pattern to build URL

Tags: php, regex, http, url, expression

I have the following URL path pattern

```
/posts(/:id:)?
```

**What would be the best way to fill it with arguments and match them against a pattern?**

Firstly, I replace the respective argument pattern (`:id:`) with the real one provided and build a *perspective* output URL

```
preg_replace_callback('~:([^:]+):~', function($match) {
    //aggregate the match &&
    //1) return the output url ||
    //2) return the output pattern
}, $pattern);
```

Depending on the argument, it might look similar to `/posts/3`. Secondly, I call the `preg_replace_callback` again to build an output pattern. Finally, I compare the two results `preg_match` to ensure segment validity. Pseudo code

```
argument => 3,     outputUrl     => /posts/3
pattern  => [\d]+, outputPatterm => /posts(/[\d]+)?

preg_match(outputPattern, outputUrl) => matches...
```

Example

```
$this->patterns = [
    'id' => '[\d]+'
];

$this->arguments = [
    'id' => 3
];

$pattern = '/posts(/:id:)?';

$outputPattern = preg_replace_callback('~:([^:]+):~', function($match){
    return $this->patterns[$match[1]];
}, $pattern);

$outputUrl = preg_replace_callback('~:([^:]+):~', function($match){
    return $this->arguments[$match[1]];
}, $pattern);

if (preg_match('~^'.$outputPattern.'$~', $outputUrl)) {
    //nice, they match. Still two preg_* methods used
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot a sample input.

Comment: @stribizhev, added one right away :)

Comment: [Your example does not compile](http://ideone.com/4pF39D).

Comment: @stribizhev it does now http://ideone.com/dsNV0L.

Comment: still error.. , now it does ;) http://ideone.com/leHuKB

Comment: @MTroy I truly hoped that it would be clear to put the snippet in class function... :) oop, whatsoever.

Comment: This is highly unclear to me. I tried the fiddle, and see that the outputUrl variable contains `(...)?`. These prevent from matching with the $outputPattern. See this [demo](http://ideone.com/TTrMG6). If I made some fixes (add `/` to the outputUrl, add regex delimiters to the outputPattern in preg_match), it starts working, see [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/3NsOAc). Now, please describe what you wish to modify here.